# /nagios/cgi-bin/statusmap.cgi was not found on this server

Tags: nagios, ubuntu

I installed Nagios 3.4.4 on Ubuntu server 12.10. Installation was successful but now I'm not able to view maps and trends.When I try, I get the following error
**`/nagios/cgi-bin/statusmap.cgi was not found on this server`** Why is this happening.What should be done for this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the fix for this:

```
[root@localhost]# make
[root@localhost]# make cgis
[root@localhost]# make install-cgis
```

Answer (score 0):

try running `sudo updatedb`
then `locate statusmap.cgi` to find this file in the filesystem.

If that file `statusmap.cgi` is installed and is in a different path on your system you may need to launch the program in a different way, set an environment variable or change a config file.